# Evaluate $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt t+ t^2)}{(4t - t^2)}$. Why is the limit as $t \to \infty = 0$?

Tags: calculus

Would like some feedback on my process. Also, would like to gain a Calculus I understanding of limits.

A question many are having a problem explaining to me is why is the limit as x approaches infinity designated as zero. Thats is, when I get to the point of solving a limit expression or function, why is it as x approaches infinity the value is designated zero?

Surely the number can be a very high positive number also? Or am I missing something here? for example why is the limit as x approached infinity $1/x = o$? What if x is 0.0001? [image]

Comment: It appears that you have several questions here.  Perhaps it would be better to separate them into individual thoughts?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$ can be seen by looking at values of $x$ that get bigger and bigger: $\frac{1}{1}=1, \frac{1}{10}=0.1, \frac{1}{100}=0.001$ and so on. We note that the as $x$ gets very large, $\frac{1}{x}$ gets very small.

Comment: The limit to your posted problem *is indeed* $-1$ and *not* $0$. If you found the solution to the exercise (text's solution?), it is mistaken (typo?).

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{(\sqrt t+ t^2)}{(4t - t^2)}$$
$$=\lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{(1+t^{3/2})}{(4\sqrt t - t^{3/2})}$$
$$=\lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{(1+t^{3/2})}{\sqrt t(4 - t)}$$
$$=\lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt t(4 - t)} + \lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac {t^{3/2}}{\sqrt t(4 - t)}$$
$$=0 + \lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac {t}{(4 - t)}$$
$$=\lim_{T \to 0} \dfrac {1/T}{4-1/T},\; \text {with} \;T=1/t$$
$$=\lim_{T \to 0} \dfrac {1}{4T-1}$$
$$=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Dividing all terms by the highest power, $t^2$, is absolutely the right move.  Leaving you with:

$\cfrac{\cfrac{1}{t^{3/2}}+1}{\cfrac{4}{t}-1}$

Now evaluating this expression as t approaches infinity is easy, as long as you are okay with $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \cfrac{C}{x^n}=0$, *C* and *n* can be any positive real number!  If you'd like an explanation of this, I suggest asking a separate question.

$\cfrac{0+1}{0-1}=-1$

(You actually had the correct answer, but you got a bit lucky since you had errors along the way.

Comment: I guess my question is if someone can explain why $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \cfrac{C}{x^n}=0/$ since if I put in a small x number such as .0001 I will get  a large output number (y value). So why designate it zero? I would like to get am intuitive answer or I guess you can also just tell me to accept it as an axiom.

Comment: If you consider a finite number for x, you will always get a finite value for the expression. But you are not asked to consider a finite number, you are asked to consider what value the expression APPROACHES as x APPROACHES infinity. Consider $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \cfrac{500}{x^{1/2}}$. When x=10000, the expression evaluates to 5. When x=100000, the expression evaluates to about 1.6. When x=1000000, the expression evaluates to 0.5. x=10000000, the expression evaluates to about 0.16. You can continue this process.  As x approaches infinity, what value does the expression approach?  0.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea dividing through by the highest power, but something went a bit wrong after that... for one, what makes you so sure you can split limits up and take them separately over the numerator and denominator? You also had a mistake cancelling out your exponents - for example, the numerator in the upper-right corner should have reduced to $1/t^{3/2} + 1$. After that, in the denominator, you also have to distribute 1/t, not put it on only one of the two terms in the numerator.

Comment: "what makes you so sure you can split limits up and take them separately over the numerator and denominator?" Why can't I. Is'nt this the process I should be taking to break down a limit expression.

Comment: "the denominator, you also have to distribute 1/t, not put it on only one of the two terms in the numerator." I divided the entire rational complex polynomial by the highest power x^2 in the denominator. If I divide 4t by t^2 I get 4/ t and if I divide -t^2 by t^2 I get -1 in the numerator of the polynomial in the denominator. I don't understand what you have said I have done wrong.

Comment: If the limits on f and g both exist then the limit of f/g is the quotient of the limits, it's totally OK...

Comment: @lolopop I know, but that fact is something that would be beneficial to Cetshwayo for solving problems in general.

Comment: @Cetshwayo You did get back to that in the end. I was referring to the part on the left of the second line where you wrote that the limit of (4-1)/t was equal to the limit of 4/t minus the limit of 1. Did you mean to write t, not 1, in the numerator? If so, then you didn't do anything wrong - sorry.